# Storing the sum of two Ints in a Long in Java

Tags: java, int, long-integer

What i want to do is basically store two int values in two variables and then store the value of an operation of the two ints in a long. The code i have is:

```
int operand1 = 2147483647;
int operand2 = 1; 
long longValue = operand1 + operand2;
```

The problem I'm having is i need longValue to be equal too 2147483648 and not -2147483648 as it is wrapping it around. I need both operand1 and 2 to remain as ints. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Cast the ints to long when adding. `long longValue = (long) operand1 + (long) operand2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast both ints to longs.

```
long longValue = ((long)operand1) + ((long)operand2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int operand1 = 2147483647;
int operand2 = 1; 
long longValue = (long) operand1 + operand2;
```

Cast only first operand1 is enough, even operand1 = 1 and operand2 = 2147483647, because long + int autocasting to long.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the solution is to cast one (or both) of the operands on the RHS (right hand side) of the assignment to `long`.  When there is an `+` operation with operand an `int` and the other a `long`, the JLS says that the program will convert the `int` operand to a `long` and perform the operation using 64 bit arithmetic.

In the code as you have written it, the JLS says that two `int` values should be added using 32 bit arithmetic.  The 32 bit to 64 bit conversion happens afterwards, as the value is being assigned.

Answer (score 1):

try it,

```
long longValue = new Long(operand1) + new Long(operand2);
```